# iOS swift: Deint a child ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

I have an UITabBar inside a ViewController. Selecting tab bar items I add different child view controller. And remove the others.

But I never see the deint log on the console, only the viewWillDisappear..

How can I be sure to deint the child viewcontroller to save memory?

**this is how I create the child controller:**

```
private lazy var lotteryViewController: LotteryViewController = {
        // Load Storyboard
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TrophyRoom", bundle: Bundle.main)

        // Instantiate View Controller
        var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LotteryViewController") as! LotteryViewController

        // Add View Controller as Child View Controller
        self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)

        return viewController
    }()
```

**add child controller:**

```
private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        // Add Child View Controller
        addChildViewController(viewController)

        // Add Child View as Subview
        containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)

        // Configure Child View
        viewController.view.frame = containerView.bounds
        viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
```

**remove method called from the father viewController:**

```
private func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)

        // Remove Child View From Superview
        viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()

        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
```

Log methods of the child controllers:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        print("Sessions View Controller Will Appear")
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        print("Sessions View Controller Will Disappear")
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        // Log if a view controller is being deinited
        print("\nDeinit: \(self.description)\n")
    }
```

Comment: Why are you expecting a log from deinit? Have you implemented you own deinit method and logged something there?

Comment: yes of course, I have deint method with print function

Comment: Use Instruments to find out whether the view controller is leaking and what is retaining it.

Comment: How are you creating your view controller and adding it to the parent view? Make sure there is no variable referencing to the view controller.

Comment: it is not leaking, it has just a label. It's impossible that it's leaking

Comment: Fine. Then something you have not told us about is retaining it.

Comment: I've updated with all the code

Comment: So isn't `lotteryViewController` the retaining reference we're talking about?

Comment: @matt yes it is, that is the child viewController that should be deint

Comment: So haven't we solved the problem? Your method for creating the child also adds an extra retaining reference to the child. Hence, no deinit.

Comment: what do you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class instance memory management works by keeping a count of retaining references. 
`deinit` means "this object is about to go out of existence because there are no more retaining references to it".

You are doing the parent-child "dance" correctly when you add a child view controller and when you remove a child view controller. So all is well from that standpoint. When you call `viewController.removeFromParentViewController`, it is certainly true that *one* retaining reference to it goes away, namely, the parent-child retaining reference (the `childControllers` array, which has removed and released the child).

But that does not mean that *all* retaining references go away. And indeed, the fact that `deinit` is *not* called signals that some *other* retaining reference exists. All you have to do now is find out what that reference is. But in fact it appears that you have shown us what it is:

```
private lazy var lotteryViewController: LotteryViewController = {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TrophyRoom", bundle: Bundle.main)
    var viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LotteryViewController") as! LotteryViewController
    self.add(asChildViewController: viewController)
    return viewController
}()
```

`lotteryViewController` is a strong (retaining) reference to the child view controller. Thus, it keeps that view controller alive even after you've removed it as a child.

So there's a weakness in (or at least an unexpected consequence of) your architecture (by which I mean your curious use of a `lazy var` instance property with a define-and-call initializer). The way to make a child view controller is to instantiate the view controller, hand it over to the parent as its child, and *let go* of the view controller so that the only reference to it is the parent. (If you need a subsequent reference to the child, you can always get it *by way of the parent*.) You are not doing that, so you don't get the `deinit` when the child is removed from the parent.